# Adding two GIFs in a single Photoshop Document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, template, cc-2019

I'm trying to make a document that has a two GIFs on it. I've figured out how to make a template, but when I try to move a GIF from its document into the template, it just becomes a still image.

I've tried making it a group and moving the whole group over and making it a smart object. I'm just never able to save it and have the two GIFs move.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the flyout menu of the Timeline panel, select the `Select All Frames` option to select the frames first

[image]

Then copy them

[image]

And paste using a method you prefer

[image]

The result with `Paste Over Selection` method:

[image]